# Pulling Table Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to pull a string from a large webpage. When I go to the table data and copy the XPath I get the following:

```
//*[@id="mainForm"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/a/text()
```

I would like to use something like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById('table_a');
var cell = table.rows[0].cells[0];
cell
```

The trouble I have is of multiple tables all lacking an identifier (id, class, etc). Every `<tr>` shares the same class of `packageLine` (there are between 500 and 1500) and there is no other identifier. Every `<td>` shares the same class of `normal` (8 per row) and there is no other identifier

I found this on the Stackoverflow site but I am not sure how to get it to apply in this case and I am not familiar with jQuery.

```
$('table:first').children('tbody').children('tr').children('td.hello')
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: you can use xpath to gather nodes... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/042xhcL3/1/

Beware, this use `textContent` so it assumes the table cells have no html within them. You'll have to adjust this but it should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thank you for your quick response. There are some major gaps in my understanding. This looks like it might work, however, there are many tables on this page and I am needing to access the third table down. If I can point the console to the correct table, it seems reasonable to expect your code will work at that point. Any thoughts?

Comment: I need to grab the contents of this cell - table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]

Comment: Eventually, after I can find and return the contents of that cell, I am planning to loop through each of the 12k <tr>s and compare the contents of the td[6] to a variable and then executing a function if it returns true. I'm not sure if this context is helpful or not, but here it is.